# No code signature found after install cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

After I installed a pod into my project, I am getting error saying

```
NO CODE SIGNATURE FOUND
```

and the project is not implemented.

I found [an article](https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2015/11/30/code-sign-error-building-cocoapods-framework-targets/) related to the issue. The article suggests that need to be include some code signing bypass to the pod file as below

```
    post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
   end
 end
```

I am using Xcode(8.1).

The remarkable thing is, I do not have a developer account.

But it does not solve my problem. What solution would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Click on your target, in the General Tab you have a Signing part, just below the Identity section.

Here you can manage your certificate and developer profile.

For more management option you can check the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/).

Here is also a good tutorial : [Code Signing Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood).

**EDIT:** I just read that you don't have a developer account.